# How to display a Javascript Tag with a src file inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display one javascript reference inside a `div` in the `body` content?

How do I insert a JS file inside the `body` part, not in the `head`, dynamically after the page loads?

HTML looks like this after the page loads:

```
<div class="cls1" id="id1">
    <script src="url" ></script>
</div>
```

I was trying,

```
$("#id1").append("<script src="www.example.com/ex.js" ></script>");
```

or

```
document.write("<script src="www.example.com/ex.js" ></script>");
```

Comment: you need to escape your inner double quotes `\"`or change the outer double quotes to single quotes

Comment: Try $("#id1").append("<script src='www.example.com/ex.js'></script>");

Comment: I was trying this didnot worked out

Comment: What exactly are you wanting the end result to be? For the actual, physical `<script>` tag to be the content of the `<div>` (as text), the script to be loaded and executed (but for the `<script>` tag to be placed inside the `<div>`), or for the content of the file referenced by the `<script>` tag to be the content of the `<div>`?

Comment: @ashokcc That's very vague and utterly unhelpful. You need to tell us *precisely* what happened, why that isn't the correct result, and what you *do* want to happen.

Comment: @Anthony I need to load a js file like  <script src="www.example.com/ex.js"></script>  inside a  <div id="id1"> </div> dynamically through Jquery

Comment: @ashokcc So you want the code inside the js file to be executed?

Comment: @ashokcc In that case, there's no real need for the `<script>` tag to be placed in a `<div>` rather than the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

`.text` will add it safely (escaping the html) while `.append` or `.html` will actually modify the dom and execute your javascript file

```
$("#id1").text('<script src="www.example.com/ex.js" ></script>');
```

Comment: Using `.text()` will just render that as text, it won't load the file.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist based on his question he wants to display it not call in to use +1

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The question I understand is about displaying the html string, not append the javascript source to the html to be executed

Comment: That's not how I interpreted the question, mainly because it makes absolutely no sense to do. Will have to wait for the person who asked the question to come along and clarify.

Answer (score -1):

You use double inverted commas in append and also use double inverted commas for src 'attribute'. You have to use single inverted commas for src 'attribute'.

Try this code:

```
$("#id1").append("<script src='www.example.com/ex.js' ></script>");
```

or

```
document.write("<script src='www.example.com/ex.js'></script>");
```